# ArrayList rangecheck error

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to refer to an arraylist I've initiated in a method, but when I try to remove something from that ArrayList, I get an error saying that the size of my ArrayList is 0. However, after I set the values of the ArrayList, it prints out the size of the ArrayList, which I have called 'school'. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.*;
public class SchoolSolver{
    public static ArrayList<Girl> school = new ArrayList<Girl>();
    public static ArrayList<Girl> used = new ArrayList<Girl>();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        resetSchool();
        //System.out.println(school.size());
        boolean notPossible = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            if(notPossible){
                resetSchool();
            } else {
                newDay();
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; i++){
                //randomGirl() is where my error happens
                Girl leader = randomGirl();
                used.add(leader);
            }
        }
    }
    /*Below are the two methods where I suspect the error may originate from */
    public static void resetSchool(){
        school.clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
            //System.out.println("ran");
            school.add(new Girl(i));
        }
        for(Girl g : school){
        ArrayList<Girl> classmates = new ArrayList<Girl>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
            if(i!= g.getID()){
                classmates.add(new Girl(i));
            }
        }
        g.setClassmates(classmates);
    }
}

public static Girl randomGirl(){
    return school.remove(0);
}
```

Thanks and I appreciate the help!

Comment: This code doesn't look like it compiles. Is this the actual code? If not, please do your part to help yourself by providing the community with your actual code so we don't chase bugs that aren't really bugs you're facing. :)  For instance, you have a for loop without a closing brace, and you've started to comment half the code without a closing comment. It makes it really hard to tell what's going on here.

Answer (score 2):

You have a never ending loop

```
for(int j = 0; j < 5; i++)
```

See how you increment `i` instead of `j`. This means you keep on calling `randomGirl`, which removes a `Girl` from the list each time it is called. So after a while (15 times) your list becomes empty, and you still call `randomGirl`, which results in the exception